# C# Console app do not exit until CTRL+C pressed without while loop

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application

because the `while()` it produce high CPU usage, how I can run async method but wait until  CTRL+C pressed before the program exit?

```
class Program
{
    public static bool isRunning = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);
        // run async method...
        Console.WriteLine("-> Press CTRL+C to Exit");
        while (isRunning) { } // <- wait but without this
    }

    static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        isRunning = false;
        Console.WriteLine("CancelKeyPress fired, exit...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your async method accept a Cancelation Token?

Comment: no Cancelation Token

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput?view=net-8.0

Comment: The behavior you've described isn't typical _Console App_ behavior. You may consider creating a _Windows Forms App_ or _WPF App_ instead. Why have you chosen to create a _Console App_?

Comment: I'd actually say that a Windows Service is more appropriate than a GUI app.

Comment: Is this something that helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586612/how-to-keep-a-net-console-app-running

Comment: `// run async method...` please show actual code, because you have `void Main` not `async Task Main`

Comment: @Charlieface its `HttpListener` with `BeginGetContext`

Comment: Can't see that in your post, but you'd need `EndGetContext` or it's just going to loop forever.

Comment: Look into Microsoft Hosting extensions (Nuget); you're reinventing a solved problem here. Console lifetime with Ctrl+C exit is one of the basic/default configs for it.